# Can I support "WhatIf" without it applying to all of the cmdlets I call?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which does a bunch of stuff (Checks some config out from Git, compares a few files, works out whether to create a package, uploads it, and then cleans up after itself).

I want to support WhatIf functionality - but *only* for the main part of the functionality - the script needs to create the temp folder, check out the config, and clean up after itself.  I just want the WhatIf to affect whether it does the package creation/upload.

However, if I put `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` into my function's header then it means that every cmdlet call that supports WhatIf then doesn't run (and this happens all the way down the call chain.

Is there any way of saying "Run everything except for the code which I've wrapped in `pscmdlet.ShouldProcess`" ?

Comment: I recommend providing a sample script that exhibits the behavior you _don't_ want and explain what you do want to happen.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work the way you expect it to you have to understand how both parameters affect preference variables inside scope of your function.

Running advanced function with `-WhatIf` will set `$WhatIfPreference` to `$true` - to avoid changing behaviour of commands you need it to set it back to `$false`, or run all commands that `SupportShouldProcess` with `-WhatIf:$false`.

Running advanced function with `-Confirm` will set `$ConfirmPreference` to 'Low' (so anything that `SupportsShouldProcess` will prompt) - to avoid changing behaviour of commands you need to set it back to 'High', or run any command that `SupportsShouldProcess` with `-Confirm:$false`.

Example code that cleans both flags (and prompts/ returns WhatIf message only when you like it to do that):

```
function Invoke-WhatIf {
    [CmdletBinding(
            SupportsShouldProcess
    )]
    param ()
    $WhatIfPreference = $false
    $ConfirmPreference = 'High'
    $null = New-Item -Path $env:TEMP\so.tmp -Force
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('whatIf message','confirm message','confirmCaption')) {
        Remove-Item $env:TEMP\so.tmp -Force
    }
}
```

Read more in [about_Preference_Variables](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables)